# Possible Genotypes -- Linked Genes

Tags: genetics, homework, recombination, genetic-linkage

Please consider the following question:

Genes A and B are located on the same chromosome. If two individuals with the genotype shown below are crossed, which genotype could be formed?
[image]
Let / represent the line in the image above.
a.)AB/ab
b.)Ab/Ab
c.)aB/aB
d.)AB/Ab

Why can't the answer to this question be all of the choices? I thought that recombination was completely randomized through the process of crossing over. Why is only one of the choices correct and how would I go about doing this on my own?

Comment: The answer is for Genes A and B on the same chromosome is
a.
AB/ab

Answer (score 2):

One of the alleles for each gene must come from the parent on the right hand side. That parent only has a and b alleles (is homozygous) - meiotic crossing over will not change this. So the offspring must inherit at least one a and one b. That should point you to the answer.